# Forget x forgot and don't understand x didn't understand

Tags: tense

I've read that is possible to say I forget or I don't understand (present tense) even if it seems past. For example:

> Q: What's the name of that new restaurant on the corner?
>   A: I'm sorry. I forget.

The same with I don't understand. The person tells me something, but I can't get the meaning, so I say:

> I'm, sorry. I don't understand.

Why and when we can use the present tense with these verbs meaning the past?

Comment: Thank you for editing it. I've started today here. I'm trying to learn all the rules.

Answer (score 1):

In both of these situations neither of you is interested in the past event but in your present state of memory or understanding. In effect, *forget* and *understand* are 'recategorized' as stative verbs reporting your present state.

Comment: How interesting. So if I want further reading I'll try to look under the stative verbs. Great! Would it be considered incorrect to say them in the past or it's a matter of choice?

Comment: @Fabibr Use past if you're talking about a past situation. "He told me, but I didn't understand".

Comment: @Fabibr Use past if you're talking about a past situation -- but don't use Stoney's example, that's still present.  "Did you put the car in the garage last night?"  "No, I forgot."  "Did you tell Mikey to put the car in the garage last night?"  "Yes, he understood."

Comment: @EllieK In what sense is "He told me but I didn't understand" present?

Comment: @StoneyB It's not, sorry.  I was providing some simple past examples.